# StringDtype data type not understood

Tags: python, pandas

When converting from an extension type, e.g. `pd.Int32Dtype()`, I get `TypeError: data type not understood`. Example:

```py
num_col_with_nan = num_col_with_nan.astype(pd.Int32Dtype()).astype("string")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting between extension types is not yet supported - see [#22384](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22384) for general overview and [#31204](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31204#issuecomment-578253063) for StringDtype in particular.

As a workaround, try casting to str first:

```py
num_col_with_nan = num_col_with_nan.astype(pd.Int32Dtype()).astype(str).astype("string")
```